# How to make logs in selenium webdriver?

Tags: logging, selenium, webdriver

I use selenium webdriver to automitize our project. There are a lot of non-readable exceptions sometimes. I need to make logs with understandable messages in case exceptions appear. How should I do it? Could you please explain it to me with examples?

Answer (score 1):

I use SLF4J logger.  I declare it at the top of my classes and I wrap all my methods in a try catch to log in case of errors.  Here is an example:

```
package com.test

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public void testMethod() {

    try {

        log.info("Clicking button.");

        driver.findElement(By.id(button_id)).click();

    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        log.error("Unable to locate button.", e);
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

You can also catch multiple exceptions like this:

```
(ExceptionA | ExceptionB | ExceptionC | ExceptionETC  e)
```

Answer (score 0):

First up is to learn more about Selenium exceptions... What they are and when/why they are thrown.  Best place to start this research is by reading through the Selenium Class Hierarchy: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/package-tree.html (this assumes you're using Java... a similar hierarchy likely exists for other language bindings as well).

Next, choose a logging framework.  You haven't specified the language in which your code is written, so you'll need to research both the logging mechanics within your chosen language binding of Selenium, as well as research common logging frameworks in your chosen language.  Java Selenium does have Log4J implemented inside the framework that may be useful.  If you want to take it a step further and do some further or custom logging, you could potentially put your own Log4J configuration to work, or utilize LogBack with SLF4J.

Once you have a grasp on the Exceptions to handle and how to log them, then it's time to update your codebase accordingly.

There are many resources online to learn these individual pieces, so I won't go into that kind of detail here, but hopefully this could get you off to a good start.  This can be a pretty large undertaking, so work in small steps, you'll get there.